# How to create custom Text Swatch product attribute using Data Patch in Magento 2

Tags: custom-attributes, swatches, magento2.4.5p1

This code only saves the value (description).
But I want to save values in ADMIN and DESCRIPTION both, can anyone help me here:

```
 private function addVisualSwatchAttribute()
        {
            /** @var EavSetup $eavSetup */
            $eavSetup = $this->eavSetupFactory->create();
    
            $eavSetup->addAttribute(
                Product::ENTITY,
                'custom_visual_swatch',
                [
                    'type' => 'int',
                    'label' => 'Custom Visual Swatch',
                    'input' => 'swatch_text',
                    'source' => '',
                    'frontend' => '',
                    'backend' => '',
                    'required' => false,
                    'user_defined' => true,
                    'global' => ScopedAttributeInterface::SCOPE_GLOBAL,
                    'visible' => true,
                    'searchable' => false,
                    'filterable' => true,
                    'comparable' => false,
                    'visible_on_front' => true,
                    'used_in_product_listing' => false,
                    'unique' => false,
                    'is_html_allowed_on_front' => true,
                    'note' => 'Custom Visual Swatch Attribute Note', // You can add a description here
                ]
            );
    
            // Add attribute options
            $optionsData = [
                ['label' => 'Option 1', 'value' => 'Option 1'],
                ['label' => 'Option 2', 'value' => 'Option 2'],
                ['label' => 'Option 3', 'value' => 'Option 3'],
                ['label' => 'Option 4', 'value' => 'Option 4'],
            ];
    
            foreach ($optionsData as $option) {
                $eavSetup->addAttributeOption([
                    'attribute_id' => $eavSetup->getAttributeId(Product::ENTITY, 'custom_visual_swatch'),
                    'value' => [
                        'option_' . $option['value'] => [$option['label']],
                    ],
                ]);
            }
    
        }
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
<?php

namespace VendorName\ModuleName\Setup\Patch\Data;

use Magento\Eav\Model\Config;
use Magento\Eav\Model\ResourceModel\Entity\Attribute\Option\CollectionFactory;
use Magento\Eav\Setup\EavSetup;
use Magento\Eav\Setup\EavSetupFactory;
use Magento\Framework\Exception\LocalizedException;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\ModuleDataSetupInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\Patch\DataPatchInterface;
use Magento\Catalog\Model\Product;
use Magento\Catalog\Model\Product\Type;
use Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Eav\Attribute as EavAttribute;
use Psr\Log\LoggerInterface;

class AddTextSwatchProductAttribute implements DataPatchInterface
{
    /**
     * @var array
     */
    protected array $optionCollection = [];

    /**
     * @var ModuleDataSetupInterface
     */
    private ModuleDataSetupInterface $moduleDataSetup;
    
    /**
     * @var EavSetupFactory
     */
    private EavSetupFactory $eavSetupFactory;
    
    /**
     * @var CollectionFactory
     */
    private CollectionFactory $attrOptionCollectionFactory;
    
    /**
     * @var Config
     */
    private Config $eavConfig;
    
    /**
     * @var LoggerInterface
     */
    private LoggerInterface $logger;

    /**
     * @param ModuleDataSetupInterface $moduleDataSetup
     * @param EavSetupFactory $eavSetupFactory
     * @param CollectionFactory $attrOptionCollectionFactory
     * @param Config $eavConfig
     * @param LoggerInterface $logger
     */
    public function __construct(
        ModuleDataSetupInterface $moduleDataSetup,
        EavSetupFactory          $eavSetupFactory,
        CollectionFactory        $attrOptionCollectionFactory,
        Config                   $eavConfig,
        LoggerInterface          $logger
    ) {
        $this->moduleDataSetup = $moduleDataSetup;
        $this->eavSetupFactory = $eavSetupFactory;
        $this->attrOptionCollectionFactory = $attrOptionCollectionFactory;
        $this->eavConfig = $eavConfig;
        $this->logger = $logger;
    }

    /**
     * @return AddTextSwatchProductAttribute|void
     */
    public function apply()
    {
        try {
            $productTypes = implode(',', [Type::TYPE_SIMPLE, Type::TYPE_VIRTUAL]);

            /** @var EavSetup $eavSetup */
            $eavSetup = $this->eavSetupFactory->create(['setup' => $this->moduleDataSetup]);

            $eavSetup->addAttribute(Product::ENTITY, 'sample_text_swatch', [
                    'type' => 'int',
                    'label' => 'Sample Text Swatch',
                    'input' => 'select',
                    'required' => false,
                    'user_defined' => true,
                    'searchable' => true,
                    'filterable' => true,
                    'comparable' => true,
                    'visible_in_advanced_search' => true,
                    'apply_to' => $productTypes,
                    'is_used_in_grid' => true,
                    'is_visible_in_grid' => false,
                    'option' => [
                        'values' => [
                            'Option1',
                            'Option2'
                        ]
                    ]
                ]
            );

            $this->eavConfig->clear();

            $this->convertAttributeToSwatches();

        } catch (\Exception $e) {
            $this->logger->critical($e);

        }
    }

    /**
     * @return void
     * @throws LocalizedException
     */
    public function convertAttributeToSwatches()
    {
        $attribute = $this->eavConfig->getAttribute('catalog_product', 'sample_text_swatch');
        if (!$attribute) {
            return;
        }

        $attributeData['option'] = $this->addExistingOptions($attribute);
        $attributeData['frontend_input'] = 'select';
        $attributeData['swatch_input_type'] = 'text';
        $attributeData['update_product_preview_image'] = 1;
        $attributeData['use_product_image_for_swatch'] = 0;
        $attributeData['optiontext'] = $this->getOptionSwatch($attributeData);
        $attributeData['defaulttext'] = $this->getOptionDefaultText($attributeData);
        $attributeData['swatchtext'] = $this->getOptionSwatchText($attributeData);
        $this->logger->log(100, print_r($attributeData, true));
        $attribute->addData($attributeData);
        $attribute->save();
    }

    /**
     * @param EavAttribute $attribute
     * @return array
     */
    private function addExistingOptions(EavAttribute $attribute): array
    {
        $options = [];
        $attributeId = $attribute->getId();
        if ($attributeId) {
            $this->loadOptionCollection($attributeId);
            /** @var \Magento\Eav\Model\Entity\Attribute\Option $option */
            foreach ($this->optionCollection[$attributeId] as $option) {
                $options[$option->getId()] = $option->getValue();
            }
        }
        return $options;
    }

    /**
     * @param int $attributeId
     * @return void
     */
    private function loadOptionCollection($attributeId)
    {
        if (empty($this->optionCollection[$attributeId])) {
            $this->optionCollection[$attributeId] = $this->attrOptionCollectionFactory->create()
                ->setAttributeFilter($attributeId)
                ->setPositionOrder('asc', true)
                ->load();
        }
    }

    /**
     * @param array $attributeData
     * @return array
     */
    private function getOptionSwatch(array $attributeData): array
    {
        $optionSwatch = ['order' => [], 'value' => [], 'delete' => []];
        $i = 0;
        foreach ($attributeData['option'] as $optionKey => $optionValue) {
            $optionSwatch['delete'][$optionKey] = '';
            $optionSwatch['order'][$optionKey] = (string)$i++;
            $optionSwatch['value'][$optionKey] = [$optionValue, ''];
        }
        return $optionSwatch;
    }

    /**
     * @param array $attributeData
     * @return array
     */
    private function getOptionDefaultText(array $attributeData): array
    {
        $optionSwatch = $this->getOptionSwatchText($attributeData);
        return [array_keys($optionSwatch['value'])[0]];
    }

    /**
     * @param array $attributeData
     * @return array
     */
    private function getOptionSwatchText(array $attributeData): array
    {
        $optionSwatch = ['value' => []];
        foreach ($attributeData['option'] as $optionKey => $optionValue) {
            $optionSwatch['value'][$optionKey] = [$optionValue, ''];
        }
        return $optionSwatch;
    }

    /**
     * @return array
     */
    public static function getDependencies()
    {
        return [];
    }

    /**
     * @return array
     */
    public function getAliases()
    {
        return [];
    }
}
```